# DocumentDB stored procedure blocked

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using a stored procedure to bulk insert documents which is taken from the [documentation sample](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#bulk-importing-data).

The documents are inserted every minute in batches, performance level of collection is S2. After about 15000 documents are inserted over a period of a few days, my stored procedure consistently gets blocked and I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ForbiddenException, message: {"Errors":["The
>   script with id 'xxx' is blocked for execution because it has violated
>   its allowed resource limit several times."]}

However, it's completely unclear what exactly I am violating - number of requests? Total number of documents? Document's size?
By looking at the DocumentDB limitations and description of performance levels I can't figure out what limitation I am hitting and what I can do to fix it. Neither do I get any warnings or alerts in the Azure portal...

What do I do in this situation? Go round-robin with multiple stored procedures ;) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was experiencing this so I came up with a workaround. Whenever I get this out of resources response, I actually remove and recreate the stored procedure. I created a library that takes care of this automatically based upon the response. It also takes care of automatic delay from throttling response and includes a bunch of other conveniences.

See:

- https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils

Answer (score 3):

Server-side scripts are resource governed in terms CPU, memory, and IO to prevent abuse and avoid noisy neighbor issues.

The Boolean flag returned from document CRUD operations is meant to signal when resources are exhausted and it's time for the the script exit gracefully.

In this case, the script properly yields to the document CRUD Boolean... This appears to be a bug on DocumentDB's side; the script should never get blacklisted. I'll cause some noise and get this fixed for you promptly.

*Update (5/5/15)*: We believe we've tracked down the bug; will attempt to deploy a fix later this week. In the mean time, here are two workarounds (choose either)... 1) You can re-create the sproc on each run. This allows you to completely side-step blacklisting. 2) For bulk-importing documents specifically, you can cap the number of documents created per run to <= 100 documents for a S1 collection and <= 1000 documents for a S3 collection. This should bring the script's resource-consumption below the current blacklisting thresholds.

*Update (6/4/15)*: We have deployed a fix; please ping me if you experience scripts getting blocked: askcosmosdb {at} microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks :) Let me know if you need any additional information about my setup.

Comment: I too am experiencing this problem. Please let me know if you need my example.

Comment: @aliuy, see my answer below for links to a new library I created that works around this issue, among other conveniences.

Comment: Awesome library! I love it. Would you mind e-mailing me your example sprocs to andrl {at} microsoft?

Comment: @Larry Maccherone Thanks, marking your suggestion as an answer as well, as it resolves the issue. Hoping though that ms would not block our whole documentdb accounts for excessive violation :) 
aliuy, It would be very nice to have this bug fixed, otherwise it's one funny database which at some point refuses to accept more data for no reason...